# How to grab a section with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'd like to grab the various sections in my code with Regular expressions. I want to write four different regex expressions. The first one is simple, which is to grab the first line that begins with the word `extends`. The next three need to grab the sections denoted `block head`, `block body`, and `block scripts`.

I'm a bit lost. So far I've got `/^block/m`

I'm not looking to respect indentation, just using it for my own visual organization.

```
extends standard

block head

  <title>title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="A wonderful thing.">

block body

  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>A wonderful paragraph...</p>

block scripts

  <script src="/javascritps/html5shiv.js"></script>
```

I need to be able to grab the identifier after the word block.

Also, separately, I need to grab the HTML content after each block ____ statement.

Comment: What will you do if the HTML contains "block"? You will need a HTML parser. You can't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Well, block will not appear after a newline. I'm open to suggestions on parsers to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a good start: here is how to do using lookbehind: `/(?<=^block )\w+\n/mg`

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/bFhNSO/1

---

**[EDIT] for explanations.**

Using a lookbehind is more complex syntax but allows you to only capture the word you need, without the word "`Block`".

Still if you don't care, or if you do it on JS you can do the same with:

`/^block (\w+)\n/mg` then you need to capture.

---

**[EDIT] After question changes.**

So for JS with no lookbehind and grabbing also the html all in one regex, you can use something like this: `/block (\w+)\n+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+\nblock|$)/g`.

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/bFhNSO/2.

*Note that I changed the flavor to js in regex101.*

---

**[EDIT] add more details.**

- First, flag `g` is for global so you can match multiple instances of
  the same pattern.
- `(\w+)` captures a word basically its like [a-z_]+ so you may want to change it to more permissive according to your needs.
- `([\s\S]*?)` captures anything, so it is like .* that you usually see, but particularly in JS you don't have the `s` flag for matching any spacing char with `.` so the longhand equivalent is `[\s\S]+`, matching any `\s` AND any NOT `\s` with `\S`. The `?` is for greediness, meaning you want to take the smallest match possible, you can try the regex without and you will understand the difference.
- `(?=\s+\nblock|$)` is a lookahead, allowed in JS, to make sure your previous match is followed by either the word `block` or the end of document with `$`.

That's it, hope it helps people! :)

Comment: Oooo fancy. That's super helpful. How do I get the HTML content in each section? Let me update my question, because both of these are essential : )

Comment: nope not supported, there is always a way to workaround though doing all the opposite using lookahead! if you are using JS add the tag to your question!

Comment: Cool. I can easily grab the line and substring or split the words.

Comment: You rock!!! Regex, always looks like magic when it grows past a few notions. Let me see if I can grasp this one.... We've removed the multi line flag because otherwise we couldn't capture more than one line of html. So the regex says `/block ` capture any instances (plural since we have the global flag set) beginning with the word 'block' followed by a space. Then capture `(\w+)` any number of word characters until `\n+` 1 or more new lines. Continue by capturing `([\s\S]*?)`, or \w\W might work too. Then I start to get lost, haha... I'm gonna research more...

Comment: haha thanks let me edit and add few more details. but u seem quite familiar already

Comment: This assumes the HTML won't contain "block". [You can't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: You are right @Oriol, to add more security you can do like `block\s+(\w+)\n+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+\n+block\s+\w+\n+|$)` but still it is not silverbulletproof haha. the presented regex is only meant for this particular example.

Comment: @Oriol, you sure? I think it only assumes the HTML won't contain the word block when it's immediately preceded by a newline. In which case, well, that's actually just fine, because that's invalid HTML anyway.

Comment: lol, that is why this is more secure `block\s+(\w+)\n+([\s\S]*?)(?=\s+\n+block\s+\w+\n+|$)` https://regex101.com/r/bFhNSO/10

Comment: @Oriol But antoni's regex has [`(?=\s+\nblock|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/bFhNSO/11) and not `(?=\s+block|$)`. If OP's html is always indented and the words like `block` are never, it should always work (: yes you can

Comment: @bobblebubble Ah, the regex101 is not updated with that. Yes, if the indentation is respected then it will work, otherwise: https://regex101.com/r/bFhNSO/12